# Fastest sort algorithm for millions of UINT64 RGBZ graphics pixels

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, sorting

I am sorting 10+ million `uint64_t`s with RGB data from .RAW files and 79% of my C program time is spent in `qsort`. I am looking for a faster sort for this specific data type.

Being RAW graphical data, the numbers are very random and ~80% unique. No partial sorting or runs of sorted data can be expected. The 4 `uint16_t`s inside the `uint64_t` are R, G, B and zero (possibly a small count <= ~20).

I have the simplest comparison function I can think of using `unsigned long long`s (you CANNOT just subtract them):

```
qsort(hpidx, num_pix, sizeof(uint64_t), comp_uint64); 
...
int comp_uint64(const void *a, const void *b)  {
    if(*((uint64_t *)a) > *((uint64_t *)b))  return(+1);
    if(*((uint64_t *)a) < *((uint64_t *)b))  return(-1);
    return(0);
}  // End Comp_uint64().
```

There was a very interesting "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf" on StackExchange, but they used `float`s. Then there are QSort, RecQuick, heap, stooge, tree, radix...

The swenson/sort looked interesting but had no (obvious) support for my datatype, `uint64_t`. And the "quick sort" time was the best. Some sources say the system `qsort` can be anything, not necessarily "Quick Sort".

A C++ sort bypasses the generic casting of void pointers and realizes great improvements in performance over C. There has to be an optimized method to slam U8s through a 64bit processor at warp speed.

---

System/compiler info:

I am currently using the GCC with Strawberry Perl

```
gcc version 4.9.2 (x86_64-posix-sjlj, built by strawberryperl.com
Intel 2700K Sandy Bridge CPU, 32GB DDR3
windows 7/64 pro

gcc -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -O4 -ffast-math -m64 -Ofast -march=corei7-avx -mtune=corei7 -Ic:/bin/xxHash-master -Lc:/bin/xxHash-master c:/bin/stddev.c -o c:/bin/stddev.g6.exe
```

---

## First attempt at a better `qsort`, `QSORT()`!

Tried to use Michael Tokarev's inline `qsort`.

"READY-TO-USE"?  From `qsort.h` documentation

```
-----------------------------
* Several ready-to-use examples:
 *
 * Sorting array of integers:
 * void int_qsort(int *arr, unsigned n) {
 * #define int_lt(a,b) ((*a)<(*b))
 *   QSORT(int, arr, n, int_lt);
--------------------------------

Change from type "int" to "uint64_t"
compile error on TYPE???
    
    c:/bin/bpbfct.c:586:8: error: expected expression before 'uint64_t'
      QSORT(uint64_t, hpidx, num_pix, islt);
```

I can't find a real, compiling, working example program, just comments with the "general concept"

```
#define QSORT_TYPE uint64_t 
#define islt(a,b) ((*a)<(*b))

uint64_t *QSORT_BASE; 
int QSORT_NELT;

hpidx=(uint64_t *) calloc(num_pix+2, sizeof(uint64_t));  // Hash . PIDX
QSORT_BASE = hpidx;
QSORT_NELT = num_pix;  // QSORT_LT is function QSORT_LT()
QSORT(uint64_t, hpidx, num_pix, islt);  
//QSORT(uint64_t *, hpidx, num_pix, QSORT_LT);  // QSORT_LT mal-defined?
//qsort(hpidx, num_pix, sizeof(uint64_t), comp_uint64); // << WORKS
```

The "ready-to-use" examples use types of `int`, `char *` and `struct elt`. Isn't `uint64_t` a type?? Try `long long`

```
QSORT(long long, hpidx, num_pix, islt); 
c:/bin/bpbfct.c:586:8: error: expected expression before 'long'
 QSORT(long long, hpidx, num_pix, islt);
```

---

## Next attempt: `RADIXSORT`:

Results:  RADIX_SORT is RADICAL!

```
  I:\br3\pf.249465>grep "Event" bb12.log | grep -i Sort       
 << 1.40 sec average
4) Time=1.411 sec    = 49.61%, Event RADIX_SORT        , hits=1
4) Time=1.396 sec    = 49.13%, Event RADIX_SORT        , hits=1
4) Time=1.392 sec    = 49.15%, Event RADIX_SORT        , hits=1
16) Time=1.414 sec    = 49.12%, Event RADIX_SORT        , hits=1

I:\br3\pf.249465>grep "Event" bb11.log | grep -i Sort 
 << 5.525 sec average  = 3.95 time slower
4) Time=5.538 sec    = 86.34%, Event QSort             , hits=1
4) Time=5.519 sec    = 79.41%, Event QSort             , hits=1
4) Time=5.519 sec    = 79.02%, Event QSort             , hits=1
4) Time=5.563 sec    = 79.49%, Event QSort             , hits=1
4) Time=5.684 sec    = 79.83%, Event QSort             , hits=1
4) Time=5.509 sec    = 79.30%, Event QSort             , hits=1
```

3.94 times faster than whatever sort `qsort` out of the box uses!

And, even more importantly, there was actual, working code, not just 80% of what you need given by some Guru who assumes you know everything they know and can fill in the other 20%.

Fantastic solution! Thanks Louis Ricci!

Comment: if your data is as random as you described, then i would say qsort would be one of the implementations with the stablest performance already.

Comment: Can you simply use the C++ sort? You can put it into a separate .cpp file with an `extern "C"` so the remainder of your code can stay in C.

Comment: @user3386109 You're thinking of RGBA. I think the Z refers to depth information. Either way, it's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)? maybe

Comment: RGBZ is for RGB_ZERO_  I smash 3 UINT16s into a UINT64 because a UINT32 is too small and neither K nor R had digital cameras with 16 bit quanta, there is no UINT48. What an egregious oversight!  I clear all 8 bytes before loading with RGB. I also add counts and other stuff to the last 2 bytes.

Comment: Qsort performance is dominated by the function calling overhead. Create your own sort, and use an inlinable compare function.

Comment: The A in RGB_A_ is usually for ALPHA channel which is either OPACITY or TRANSPARENCY: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space

Comment: @BrianP007 - Since 16bits of the 64bits are zero you can comment out the 2 for loops under the *//radix* comment that deal with those bits and get another ~20% speedup.

Comment: the compare function that you posted sorts first by the intensity of the color red then by the color blue then by the color green then by the transparency.   What do you want the sort criteria to be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use Radix Sort with an 8bit radix. For 64bit values a well optimized radix sort will have to iterate over the list 9 times (one to precalculate the counts and offsets and 8 for 64bits/8bits). 9*N time and 2*N space (using a shadow array).

Here's what an optimized radix sort would look like.

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        uint32_t c8[256];
        uint32_t c7[256];
        uint32_t c6[256];
        uint32_t c5[256];
        uint32_t c4[256];
        uint32_t c3[256];
        uint32_t c2[256];
        uint32_t c1[256];
    };
    uint32_t counts[256 * 8];
} rscounts_t;

uint64_t * radixSort(uint64_t * array, uint32_t size) {
    rscounts_t counts;
    memset(&counts, 0, 256 * 8 * sizeof(uint32_t));
    uint64_t * cpy = (uint64_t *)malloc(size * sizeof(uint64_t));
    uint32_t o8=0, o7=0, o6=0, o5=0, o4=0, o3=0, o2=0, o1=0;
    uint32_t t8, t7, t6, t5, t4, t3, t2, t1;
    uint32_t x;
    // calculate counts
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        t8 = array[x] & 0xff;
        t7 = (array[x] >> 8) & 0xff;
        t6 = (array[x] >> 16) & 0xff;
        t5 = (array[x] >> 24) & 0xff;
        t4 = (array[x] >> 32) & 0xff;
        t3 = (array[x] >> 40) & 0xff;
        t2 = (array[x] >> 48) & 0xff;
        t1 = (array[x] >> 56) & 0xff;
        counts.c8[t8]++;
        counts.c7[t7]++;
        counts.c6[t6]++;
        counts.c5[t5]++;
        counts.c4[t4]++;
        counts.c3[t3]++;
        counts.c2[t2]++;
        counts.c1[t1]++;
    }
    // convert counts to offsets
    for(x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
        t8 = o8 + counts.c8[x];
        t7 = o7 + counts.c7[x];
        t6 = o6 + counts.c6[x];
        t5 = o5 + counts.c5[x];
        t4 = o4 + counts.c4[x];
        t3 = o3 + counts.c3[x];
        t2 = o2 + counts.c2[x];
        t1 = o1 + counts.c1[x];
        counts.c8[x] = o8;
        counts.c7[x] = o7;
        counts.c6[x] = o6;
        counts.c5[x] = o5;
        counts.c4[x] = o4;
        counts.c3[x] = o3;
        counts.c2[x] = o2;
        counts.c1[x] = o1;
        o8 = t8; 
        o7 = t7; 
        o6 = t6; 
        o5 = t5; 
        o4 = t4; 
        o3 = t3; 
        o2 = t2; 
        o1 = t1;
    }
    // radix
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        t8 = array[x] & 0xff;
        cpy[counts.c8[t8]] = array[x];
        counts.c8[t8]++;
    }
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        t7 = (cpy[x] >> 8) & 0xff;
        array[counts.c7[t7]] = cpy[x];
        counts.c7[t7]++;
    }
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        t6 = (array[x] >> 16) & 0xff;
        cpy[counts.c6[t6]] = array[x];
        counts.c6[t6]++;
    }
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        t5 = (cpy[x] >> 24) & 0xff;
        array[counts.c5[t5]] = cpy[x];
        counts.c5[t5]++;
    }
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        t4 = (array[x] >> 32) & 0xff;
        cpy[counts.c4[t4]] = array[x];
        counts.c4[t4]++;
    }
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        t3 = (cpy[x] >> 40) & 0xff;
        array[counts.c3[t3]] = cpy[x];
        counts.c3[t3]++;
    }
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        t2 = (array[x] >> 48) & 0xff;
        cpy[counts.c2[t2]] = array[x];
        counts.c2[t2]++;
    }
    for(x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        t1 = (cpy[x] >> 56) & 0xff;
        array[counts.c1[t1]] = cpy[x];
        counts.c1[t1]++;
    }
    free(cpy);
    return array;
}
```

**EDIT** this implementation was based on a JavaScript version [Fastest way to sort 32bit signed integer arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082425/fastest-way-to-sort-32bit-signed-integer-arrays-in-javascript)

Here's the IDEONE for the C radix sort http://ideone.com/JHI0d9

Comment: Radix sort doesn't have too many uses, but it's nearly perfect for sorting pixels. Unfortunately the one time I had to sort pixels I didn't realize it until I had implemented something else.

Comment: with 'size' being in the millions, that 'malloc' will be huge.

Comment: maybe a simpler counting sort (of similar `O(n)` complexity) would do as well

Comment: @user3629249 - 10million uint64's * 8 bytes = 80million bytes ~= 80MB, I think a modern computer can handle an 80MB allocation. There are inplace versions of radix sort to avoid the the shadow array allocation but this version seems fast enough.

Comment: @NikosM. - I think you'd find the counting sort would turn into a radix sort. The elements being sorted are uint64 values so for counting sort you'd need a count array of size 2^64 (for this specific problem 16bits of those 64 are zero so you'd only need 2^48 which is still huge).

Comment: Ive had a look at this implementation, and Im not certain I understand why array is being returned, since it is a input pointer in the first place? Ie, the array will be written to.

Comment: Would a 16 bit radix be slower despite using fewer passes?

Comment: @Anush -Yes, using larger radix like 16bit instead of 8 tend to be slower. The larger "counts" arrays 65536 vs 256 are prone to more cache misses when loading data from them during each pass.

Comment: That's really interesting and not very obvious given how small 65536 is.

Answer (score 4):

I see a few options, roughly in order of easiest to hardest.

- Enable link-time optimization with the `-flto` switch. This *may* get the compiler to inline your comparison function. It's too easy not to try.
- If LTO has no effect, you can use an inline qsort implementation like [Michael Tokarev's inline qsort](http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/qsort.html). [This page](http://www.lemoda.net/c/inline-qsort-example/) suggests a 2x improvement, again solely due to the compiler's ability to inline the comparison function.
- Use the C++ `std::sort`. I know your code is in C, but you can make a small module that only sorts and provides a C interface. You're already using a toolchain that has great C++ support.
- Try [swenson/sort](https://github.com/swenson/sort)'s library. It implements many algorithms so you can use the one that works best on your data. It appears to be inlineable, and they claim to be faster than `qsort`.
- Find another sorting library. Something that can do Louis' Radix Sort is a good suggestion.

Note you can also do your comparison with a single branch instead of two. Just find out which is bigger, then subtract.

Comment: Subtracting two `uint64_t` might generate a value that doesn't fit into an `int`. If not for that you could eliminate the branches altogether and just return the result of the subtraction.

Comment: >> Subtracting two uint64_t might generate a value that doesn't fit into an int. I found out that half of the subtractions generated negative results  which screwed up the entire sort.  The dual step process was designed to sidestep this problem.  I have switched to RADIX_SORT anyway; 4X faster!

Comment: @BrianP007 the other issue with subtracting unsigned ints is that they cannot be negative.

Comment: @BrianP007 if you decided to go with Louis' answer, you should mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark next to his answer.

Answer (score 1):

With some compilers/platforms the following is branch-less and faster, though not much different than OP's original.

```
int comp_uint64_b(const void *a, const void *b)  {
    return 
     (*((uint64_t *)a) > *((uint64_t *)b)) - 
     (*((uint64_t *)a) < *((uint64_t *)b));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe some ?: instead of ifs would make things a tad quicker.

Comment: Micro-optimizations like this are usually bad - let the compiler do its thing.

Comment: That's highly unlikely. Any competently constructed compiler will generate the same code for a traditional `if ... else` and the corresponding ternary (i.e. `?:`) expression.